# Entity Framework .Any() is returning the full table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm pretty sure that I'm just being ridiculously stupid, but I can't seem to figure this out...

I have the following objects in EF6 code first:

```
public class Vessel
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Position> Positions {get;set;}
}

public class Position
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public double Lat {get;set;}
  public double Lon {get;set;}

  public virtual Vessel Vessel {get;set;}
}
```

I am doing the following:

```
var vess = context.Vessels.First();

if (vess.Positions.Any())
{
  // Do something spiffy
}
```

I'm profiling this in Rhinos, and the following SQL is being generated:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Id]                AS [Id],
       [Extent1].[VesselId]          AS [VesselId],
       [Extent1].[Lat]               AS [Lat],
       [Extent1].[Lon]               AS [Lon]
FROM   [dbo].[Position] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  [Extent1].[VesselId] = 1 /* @EntityKeyValue1 */
```

My question is, why? I might as well have written:

```
if (vess.Positions.Count() > 0)
```

Like I say, I'm sure I'm just being stupid.

Answer (score 3):

Since `Positions` is defined as an `ICollection<Position>`, the compiler is binding `Any` to the `Enumerable` (Linq-to-objects) extension method, which just checks for the presence of an item in the collection.  By doing so, it calls the getter of the virtual `Positions` property which has been overridden by EF to load the *full* contents of the collection by generating the SQL you see.

> I might as well have written `if (vess.Positions.Count() > 0)`

No, that would do the same thing for the same reason.

If this is *really* a problem and just not what you expected, you'd have to build up the equivalent EF query:

```
var positions = context.Positions
                       .Where(p => p.VesselId == vess.Id);

if (positions.Any())
{
  // Do something spiffy
}
```

But I would not that if "something spiffy" entails doing something with the `Positions` property contents, you might as well just load it within the `if` clause like you're doing now.

Comment: Thanks, I'd just written similar code against the context after posting. Is there an idiomatic way to do this, it seems that having the child collection is fairly pointless if it is going to do a full get?

Comment: If all you care about is if a position exists, then yes it is doing more than you need.  However, the idiomatic use case is to load the contents when "getting" the property.

Comment: I think that what I want to know, is how should I do: var vessels = context.Vessels.Where(v=>v.Positions.Any()); in EF?

Comment: Hmmm, ok, so that actually works.... but only because the query is being generated against the DbSet

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean  "the query is being generated against the DbSet" - but yes if you just want vessels that have positions that should work.